# Is the order of an unordered map always the same for a given compiler?

Tags: c++, g++, standards, clang++, unordered-map

I just found a bug in my code that depends on the order the elements are stored in an `unordered_map`. Ok not a big deal, I'm going to fix it. My question is only out of curiosity to understand different implementations in different compilers.

When compiled on my computer (linux `g++`) my unit tests always works because the `unordered_map` is ordered always the same and the order does not trigger my bug.

When compiled on another computer and architecture (mac M1, `clang++`) my bug is always triggered because the elements always come in the same order, which is different from with `g++`.

When compiler on my computer with `clang++`: no bug.

In my specific case the key of the `unordered_map` is an `int` and the hash is the default one for an `int` I did not used a custom hash function.

My questions are thus: how the order of an `unorderd_map` depend on the compiler implementation? I've always assumed it was somewhat random, but I was wrong, it is stable for each compiler I tested. What the standard says about that? What are the typical implementations to order an `unordered_map`?

Comment: what is `key_type`? what hash do you use?

Comment: the key is an `int` in this case

Comment: It's not specified. It is only required that `std::hash` returns the same values for duration of the program. Potentially a standard library implementation could seed some hasher on program start to make it more secure. Whether any implementation does anything like that - I don't know

Comment: [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) is implementation defined. Not sure if there is much more to learn about what determines the order. Its certainly not random, but as the hash is implementation defined, nothing else can make it less implementation defined, unless you use your custom hash

Comment: It is not random, it would be a waste of time to randomize the content of an unordered_map, so of course that it should be stable for a given implementation (i.e. for a given compiler).

Comment: ...and because that makes a whole lot of a difference you should mention what hash you use. Its the hash that determines the order

Comment: Ok so it is only a question on the default `hash` method for a given compiler. I assumed that hashing an int was somehow standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is the order of an unordered map alway the same for a given compiler?**

No.

There are a few things at play here:

- the bucket to which an element hashes depends on:

  - the hash function used, and while `std::hash<int>` is implementation defined, to the best of my knowledge all versions of GCC, Clang and Visual C++ over the last couple decades have used identity hashes
  - the bucket_count, as the `size_t` value returned by `std::hash` is generally `%`-ed or `&`-ed into the current `bucket_count()`; GCC uses prime numbers for bucket counts, while Visual C++ uses powers of two (more collision prone, but bitwise-AND is faster than a mod operation); while the default `max_load_factor()` at which rehashing occurs is specified in the Standard (at 1.0), the initial size of the table and amount by which it grows during rehashing are unspecified
- once a bucket is identified, it's up to the implementation whether it inserts elements at the start, the end, or somewhere in the middle of the chain of elements associated with that bucket
- it's up to the implementation how iteration is orchestrated; in the case of GCC, there's actually one singly-linked list of all the key/value nodes, and that's iterated without reference to the buckets; all nodes in that list with keys hashing to the same bucket are grouped together in the singly-linked list (in unspecified order), with buckets effectively holding iterators into the singly-linked list, but other choices could be made (though achieving O(1) iterator advancement in a large table in which most elements have been erased can't be done by checking every bucket, so some cleverness is needed)
- what relative order elements with the same hash have after rehashing/resizing of the table is unspecified (i.e. how they're linked into the new larger table)

So, even with the hash values the same, a lot of things could cause iteration to vary.  There's no particular reason to expect iteration order to vary *for the same Standard Library implementation* (more relevant here than the compiler per se) after the same insert/erase operations are done with the same keys, but no guarantees either.

Answer (score 3):

The hash function determines in which bucket an element gets placed. `std::unordered_map<Key,T>` uses `std::hash<Key>` as default hasher. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

> The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent and are not required to fulfill any other quality criteria except those specified above. Notably, some implementations use trivial (identity) hash functions which map an integer to itself. In other words, these hash functions are designed to work with unordered associative containers, but not as cryptographic hashes, for example.

And that implies that the resulting order you get depends on the implementation.

> I assumed that hashing an int was somehow standard.

Implementation defined is "somehow standard" ;). Hash functions is still topic of research. Choosing an optimal hash is not simple and it would be bad if the standard would fix one particular hash that is state of the art now, but outdated in a year or so.

Comment: Assuming that I'm using my own hash. Would the order be the same for each compiler?

Comment: @JRR afaik within a bucket the implementation can do whatever it likes as long as it gets the guaranteed time complexities. I'd have to dig deeper to know for sure, but the simple answer is: elements in an `std::unordered_map` do not follow any particular order, if your code relies on some particular order, its a bug.

Comment: Yes sure it is a bug. My question was more like: is an unordered_map "sorted" by hash value and thus looks randomly ordered for the user view point.

Comment: @JRR "randomly" is the wrong word. Please note that "random" has a meaning and that is not just the absence of one specific ordering. What you mean is the latter.

Comment: @JRR https://eel.is/c++draft/unord#map.overview-1 : "An unordered_map is an unordered associative container ..." it is an unordered container. That does not imply that the order you get must be different each time or differ with compiler, it just means there is no specified order. Nobody bothers about it, because it is unordered. Consider that an "unordered sequence of numbers" can be `1 2 3 4 5`, its just coincidence that you can see some ordering, but thats only your faulty interpretation,  because `1 3 2 4 5` is the same unordered sequence

Comment: ...well not the best example, my point is just that even if you find that the order is same with different compilers, I don't expect something in the standard that specifies the order, because it specifically says its unordered.